# I am not able to drag and select a query in BigQuery Editor using mouse or touchpad

Tags: google-bigquery

[image]
When I try to drag and select the query, only partial query is getting selected.
I tried to change browser, but even that didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Reload the page, that should fix it. But sometimes it appears again and u need to reload the page again.
Be careful when reloading the page because u can lose the query, so copy and paste it in another place just in case.